# how to access meteor ReactiveVar variable in meteor call in onRendered

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to access ReactiveVar variable in onRendered getting error 
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'getUsersData': TypeError: Cannot read property 'userData' of null

```
    Template.editAdmin.onCreated(function() {
     this.userData = new ReactiveVar([]);
   });

   Template.editAdmin.onRendered(function() {
     Meteor.call("getUsersData", this.data, function(err, result) {
        Template.instance().editAdminId.set(result);
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your code sample lines up with your error message. You mentioned the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userData' of null
```

but from looking at your code sample, I can see the error will really be:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'editAdminId' of null
```

I'll assume you want it working with `userData`, so I'll adjust your code accordingly. Basically you want to make sure you're leveraging javascript closure properly when using `Template.instance()` in your Method callback. For example:

```
Template.editAdmin.onCreated(function () {
  this.userData = new ReactiveVar([]);
});

Template.editAdmin.onRendered(function () {
  const instance = Template.instance();
  Meteor.call("getUsersData", this.data, function (err, result) {
    instance.userData.set(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Also `this` inside `onCreated` and `onRendered` is equal to `Template.instance()`.